# Move product bundles to stock moves in inventory and decrement from stock

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-10

How to move product bundles to stock moves in inventory and deduct all product that are in bundle from stock.

For example,

I have added multiple products under a single product(product bundles or product pack) and i want to deduct quantity of all product pack also from inventory. Currently it is only decreasing a single product.

So, May i get some help on this?